# Instalação do Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Segui o texto de instalação do laravel que está no site oficial e me retornou os seguintes erros.

> Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\primeiro_app_laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\primeiro_app_laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\primeiro_app_laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\primeiro_app_laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Para instalar o composer eu praticamente fiz next next next e digitei os comandos que estavam no site do mesmo.

Comment: Qual a versão do seu PHP ?

Comment: Estou usando a versão 5.6.

Comment: Tens o openssl ativado no php.ini? Se não tiveres, ativa e depois corre: composer update

Answer (score 0):

O laravel não está a encontrar as pastas e ficheiros.

Abre o teu cmd, vai a pasta do teu projecto e fazer o comando "composer install".